# Query on how to connect instances using EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am worried that this question is naive. But i am not being able to do a simple thing. - I am trying to use EC2 on AWS to connect to the instances I have created on Linux. I have selected the instance on Linux and selected "connect". However, I am getting an error that i am unable to solve:

> Failed to connect to your instance
> EC2 Instance Connect is unable to connect to your instance. Ensure your instance network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect. For more information, see [Set up EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html).

Kindly assist.
Many thanks in advance.

I was expecting to connect instances using Linux on AWS.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the referenced AWS documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options on how to connect to your Linux EC2 instances. The most common one is via SSH, but as you discovered there also is EC2 Instance Connect and SSM Session Manager. Setup of SSH and EC2 Instance Connect has some similar steps.

In order to be able to use the EC2 Instance Connect, [the EC2 must have the EC2 Instance Connect installed and set-up](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-prerequisites.html#eic-prereqs-amis). This is already done on EC2s launched from Amazon Linux 2023, Amazon Linux 2 and Ubuntu 20.04+ AMIs. If you used some other AMI, then you have to install it yourself. You'd probably want to do that by using a Launch Template's userdata.

Then [the EC2 must have a security group attached](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-prerequisites.html#ec2-instance-connect-setup-security-group) to it that allows incoming SSH traffic either from your IP address if you have a static one or you can allow traffic from anywhere by using `0.0.0.0/0`. Although I wouldn't recommend this for any other use case than learning or testing.

Apart from the security group the [EC2 must also have a static public IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-prerequisites.html#eic-prereqs-network-access). It'll get one when you launch it in your public subnet. You could also of course connect to a private EC2 but that would require additional work to setup a VPN connection.

Then finally the IAM user or role that you're logged in with into AWS Management Console [must be allowed to start the EC2 Instance Connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-configure-IAM-role.html). Now you should be ready to go and connect to the EC2 instance.

The documentation you linked provides all the necessary information but it's very dense and can be hard to navigate through for beginners. Don't give up!

Comment: On the topic of public IPs, launching an EC2 instance into a public subnet is not necessarily sufficient. Each subnet has an attribute that determines whether or not instances launched into that subnet receive a public IP. So, either that attribute must be set for the subnet in question (default subnets have this attribute set to true by default) or you have to explicitly request a public IP at launch time.